# Scale a UIElement at its center using Matrix in UWP

Tags: c#, math, matrix, uwp

I'm trying to scale a UIElement from its center using the MatrixTransform property, but I can't get it to work.

For the context, I'm currently writing a note application which has an infinite viewport, and the user can draw and add bitmaps. I want to implement zoom, so I decided to use Matrices and the MatrixTransform property of UIElement to scale each bitmaps according to the current zoom level (which is set by the mouse wheel).

I will modify the code so it will zoom based on the cursor's positon, but for now I want to zoom from the origin center of each bitmaps on the screens. Here's my current code:

```cs
foreach (var element in source) {

    var matrix = element.TransformMatrix;

    // note: DesignerItem is the actual bitmap image I want to transform.
    // GetLocation returns a rect that contains the element's current size
    var bounds = (element as DesignerItem).GetLocation();

    // actualBounds contains the current element's position and size including all
    // applied transformations.
    var actualBounds = new Rect() {
        X = bounds.X * matrix.M41,            // translate X
        Y = bounds.Y * matrix.M42,            // translate Y
        Width = bounds.Width * matrix.M11,    // scale X
        Height = bounds.Height * matrix.M22   // scale Y
    };

    System.Drawing.PointF location = new System.Drawing.PointF(
        (float)actualBounds.X + (float)actualBounds.Width / 2.0f, 
        (float)actualBounds.Y + (float)actualBounds.Height / 2.0f
    );

    var offset = new Vector3(
        (float)(actualBounds.X - location.X),
        (float)(actualBounds.Y - location.Y),
        0.0f
    );

    matrix *= Matrix4x4.CreateScale(_currentZoomFactor, _currentZoomFactor, 1.0f, offset);
        element.TransformMatrix= matrix;
}
```

Any ideas? I'm not particularly good at maths, and struggle with that since a long time :(
If you want other explanations or screenshots that shows the current behavior, feel free to ask.

**Edit**

Here's the `GetLocation()` function:

```cs
public Rect GetLocation()
{
    // note: _actualControl is the root container that stores my image.
    // This control allows its content to be scaled (as Photoshop do with 
    // its transform rectangle tool)
    FrameworkElement content = ItemContent as FrameworkElement;
    return new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(_actualControl), Canvas.GetTop(_actualControl),
                _actualControl.ActualWidth, _actualControl.ActualHeight);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `GetLocation` function to help me understand the the position of your element? Can [ScaleTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.scaletransform?view=winrt-22621#examples) meet your needs?

Comment: Of course! I will update my post so the code will be accessible to everyone.

Comment: I know you want to zoom from the origin center, could you describe in detail the current behavior of your program? For example, how does the center point move?

Comment: It's hard to describe, but the element's position seems to be random everytime I zoom in or out. For example, if the picture is at the center of the render area, it will then teleport to the right top or to any position on the left...